# Re-render view after remote => "true" call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to re-render a view in Rails 4.0 after clicking on a "star" button, which marks an Article as favorite.

The view **show.html.erb** is as follows:

```
<% if article.star == "yes" %>
  <%= link_to raw("<i class='fa fa-star fa-lg'></i>"), channel_article_star_path(@channel.id, article.id), method: :put, :remote => true %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to raw("<i class='fa fa-star-o fa-lg'></i>"), channel_article_star_path(@channel.id, article.id), method: :put, :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

Then, I have the following controller, **articles_controller.rb**:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def star_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    if @article.star == "no"
      @article.update_attributes(star: "yes")
    else
      @article.update_attributes(star: "no")
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :template => "channels/#{params[:channel_id]}" }
    end  
  end
end
```

The idea is that by rendering the view again, after clicking on the link I would get the correct CSS class shown. Right now, it's correctly calling the star_article action, because after refreshing the page I see the correct CSS class, but that's only after a manual refresh.
The `respond_to` method seems to not be doing what it's supposed to.

Should I be using jQuery, or what am I missing here? How can I automatically refresh the view without calling the associated path, avoiding refreshing the whole page? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to render via ajax using action.js.erb format

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def star_article
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    if @article.star == "no"
      @article.update_attributes(star: "yes")
    else
      @article.update_attributes(star: "no")
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js 
    end  
  end
end
```

and you should create a file named as star_article.js.erb 
having content

```
$("#container_id").html("<%= escape_javascript(partial to re render name) %>">
```